# Static vs Singleton

Tags: apex, design-patterns

In a recent post, someone asked about implementing the Singleton Pattern in Apex, and I offered this [link](http://www.tgerm.com/2010/03/apex-implementing-singleton-design.html) as a resource, and there was also [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sd_n_hbVuBE) session at DF 11 that talked about the Singleton pattern. @kraybill suggested that a **stateful** singleton in Apex didn't really exist/make sense, but that made me wonder whether using it for a non-stateful purpose is also an overkill. The DF 11 session explains how you could use it for as a RecordType Lookup Cache Utility to avoid multiple describes - and I have such a need for a trigger handler class I am building. But I know I could also just add a couple of static map variables to a class, and a getter that populates the map if it is null, which would achieve the same thing. So are there are pros-cons to either approach? If the Singleton pattern is not appropriate here, is there a time when it is? Any insights appreciated!

Comment: I agree with both Matt and Jeremy.

You might confuse other developers by calling it a Singleton when it only restricts the instantiation of that class to the current request. Two simultaneous requests would have different instances where the singleton pattern would imply you only have one.

The only advantage I can think of is the lazy initialization or whatever occurs in the classes constructor.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I had the same initial response that the correct use of Static should be sufficient, but figured I must be missing something when I kept seeing the Singleton pattern being referenced...

Comment: Patterns help make code more readable and help make code more reliable.  The idea is to widely share solutions that work so that new developers can solve problems quickly and can understand the purpose of existing code more easily.  As I commented below, Salesforce published sample code that did not follow the Singleton pattern as a solution to avoid recursion in Triggers, but the code they published was flawed. Using Singleton could have given them a reliable solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Singletons not only are not needed in Apex, they are basically pointless. In that previous thread, I described why stateful singletons are pointless, but stateless singletons are pretty much in the same boat, simply because the instantiation/cache step is unnecessary.

In Apex, I've found that abstract utility classes with all-static methods are the equivalent of a Java/Spring service layer (without dependency injection). In practice they behave the same as a stateless singleton class anyway. We have dozens of these in our app, which are used to do anything servicey, such as the describe call caching you mentioned.

When you're in an environment that is born and dies within the scope of a single (single-threaded) request, the singleton pattern is irrelevant. Static achieves the same ends, including state sharing within the request if that's what you need.

Comment: One advantage a singleton has is that if it stored as a member of a controller or batch apex class (that implementes stateful) it can be serialized to keep it's state for the scope of the task. A rare need certainly, but something that can happen.

Comment: In those cases, why is a singleton necessary? Just a normal object instance will work fine for serializing state.

Comment: Admittedly there are few use cases, but let's say you have a computationally expensive cache, say tax calculations, that you want to keep in viewstate, but your logic is independent of the controller that's using it. You can either copy your static variables to the controller (breaking encapsulation and DRY) or just include the singleton as a private property on the controller.

Comment: @ca_peterson - no singleton necessary. private MyCache cacheInstance = new MyCache();

Comment: Arguing against myself, here's another great reason to not use singletons: there are sneaky ways to instantiate multiple objects: https://twitter.com/rich_unger/status/321452850167304192

Comment: Resurrecting this old thread to see if there are any new thoughts.  I see a cookbook pattern using a static variable to control recursion fails to work as expected for >200 records according to comments: https://developer.secure.force.com/cookbook/recipe/controlling-recursive-triggers

Comment: Judging by the Cookbook example, we *need* widely published patterns, singleton included, because they exemplify one correct way to achieve a predictable goal in a way that can be easily recognized and interpreted by the folks who have to maintain the code. Sure, it's not the only way to do a thing, but if it helps avoid errors like we see in the Cookbook code then it serves its purpose.

Comment: What is the flaw with the Trigger recursion solution?  The cookbook link no longer appears to be valid.
I have a utility Class, whose methods may be called multiple times during a transaction, and there is a SOQL query that I only want to run once.  With no development experience outside Apex, I would have put my query result into a Class variable, similar to the 'Boolean isFirstRun' Trigger recursion approach.  Is there a flaw with this?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion `static` is all you really need when working in this environment due to the fact that code runs in a new context each time the user performs an action.

I've used singletons a lot when writing games, typically I'll have a single instance of a class called SoundManager, one called InputManager, and a bunch of others that are responsible for managing particular interfaces and resources. In this context you wouldn't want to have more than one instance to keep memory usage at a minimum, but you may not want to flexibility to destroy objects when they're not needed.

For example, a front-end menu manager would likely not be needed in-game, so it's prudent to delete it and free up the memory it's using. When you're back in the front end you can create a new singleton instance and wouldn't want to have more than instance trying to manage the display.

Answer (score 3):

Singletons have a purpose in APEX. The real power in it lies in avoiding multiple queries in the same trigger context. In a complicated trigger; this is crucial when we consider Salesforce governor limits.

Comment: @AcMEGC, can you clarify how the result is different from storing the results of a SOQL query into a static List-typed variable of a "Utility"-typed class, and using "lazy" invocation of the query (not re-invoking it if the list isn't null) in a plain old static method in that "Utility"-typed class?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am going about it wrong but this pattern has become extremely useful in a service class used across multiple classes/methods both within the current namespace and from extension namespaces.

The service class sets multiple values based on dynamic apex and org shape that if executed each time would decrease performance and potentially cause collision based on the entry point.

Especially when the order of operations is critical or when specifying initialization properties that could differ depending on the entry point.

Just thought I would add my 0.0000001 cents to the discussion

Answer (score 0):

I am not comfortable with static. And the top voted answer is miss-leading. Whenever there is a static class, there should be a singleton service class, so during unit test it is possible to be replaced with a mockup service. Here are some other differences citied from another [Singleton vs Static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern) thread:

> “The big difference between a singleton and a bunch of static methods is that singletons can implement interfaces (or derive from useful base classes, although that’s less common, in my experience), so you can pass around the singleton as if it were “just another” implementation.”

> A singleton allows access to a single created instance - that instance (or rather, a reference to that instance) can be passed as a parameter to other methods, and treated as a normal object.
> A static class allows only static methods.

Think about the case of cache services, with singleton we can achieve some OO techniques to separate the concerns:
[image]

Here is an [Apex DI](https://github.com/apexfarm/ApexDI) framework you can use to easily register singleton services:

```
DI.IServiceProvider provider = new DI.ServiceCollection()
    .addSingleton(UISettingCacheService.class)
    .addSingleton(ProductCategoryCacheService.class)
    .addTransient(IAccountService.class, AccountService.class)
    .buildServiceProvider();
```